# In a frame of reference, can we have one reference point or more than one?

Tags: reference-frames, geometry

When I was finding definition of reference frame on wikipedia ; I found the following thing apart from definition .

For $n$ dimensions, $n + 1$ reference points are sufficient to fully define a reference frame.
I just want the above line explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think it means you need to fix a point as the origin and then you need $n$ unit vectors for an n-dimensional frame of reference. If we consider the tips of the unit vectors and the origin as reference points then we need $(n+1)$ reference points to define the frame of reference.
All the other points in the frame of reference can be written as a linear combination of the unit vectors.